# Passing data from MainActivity to sub-Activity when sub-Activity is opened through an Adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, in-app-purchase, android-adapter

So my title may be hard to follow, but I'll try to clarify and expand on what my issue is below.

- I currently have an app that starts its life as a MainActivity with multiple Fragments sitting in a ViewPager.
- In the MainActivity, I have Android In-App Billing V3 (library) setup so that the user can pay to remove ads. This works just fine in the MainActivity but my issue arises when moving to another Activity.
- The first Fragment the user is presented with upon launching the app, contains a RecyclerView with an ArrayList of items. To get to a sub-Activity from the MainActivity, the user presses a button on one of the items in the RecyclerView, which means that the Intent data used to change Activities is contained within the RecyclerViewAdapter.
- My issue is that once my app knows that the user has paid to remove ads, I want the app to also remove ads in all sub-Activities as well.
- I don't know how to pass this info (that the "Remove Ads" in-app has been purchased) from Activity -> sub-Activity, when sub-Activity is launched through the RVAdapter instead.
- So my question is: How would I pass data from MainActivity -> RVAdapter -> Sub-Activity?
- Or is there an even better, more efficient way of passing this data along without using Intents? Do let me know!

Did my description of the issue make sense? I hope so! Otherwise let me know how I might clarify it! If you need me to paste in any code, let me know as well.

Thanks for any of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use EventBus (greenrobot) nice library for send event this [linke](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#add-eventbus-to-your-project)

**to send evnts**

after add library  put below method to your main activity:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event)
```

don't forget about Register and unregister  subscriber, do it  like this :

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
 super.onStart();
 EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

 @Override
public void onStop() {
 super.onStop();
 EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

finally post your event from everywhere like your  subactivity :

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent());
```

Notice:I add postSticky(); to cache data on memory ,Then the sticky event can be delivered to subscribers or queried explicitly.

**better solution**

but i  think you can save value in Sharedpreferences after purcahse:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 
 MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putBoolean("pay", true);
 editor.apply();
```

then check this valu every Activity on onCreat method
to show adds or don't

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
pay = prefs.getBoolean("pay", false);
if (pay) {

    show();
 }else dontShow();
```

Comment: The `SharedPreferences` solution is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer amin! I will try out that method and get back to you on whether it worked!

Comment: That `SharedPreferences` method works really well and is a very simple method to implement. Thanks a bunch, amin. Solved.